# what e.preventDefault() method really does?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tried preventDefault() for submiting the form without page reload but its not giving any result to me.  Can anyone explain what is the purpose of preventDefault() method in JQuery???

Comment: Take a look at http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer, from http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

> Description: If this method is called, the default action of the event
>   will not be triggered.

Take this example:

```
$("a").click(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $("<div>")
    .append( "default " + event.type + " prevented" )
    .appendTo( "#log" );
});
```

If the hyperlink above is clicked then the browser will not try to redirect the browser (because of the `preventDefault()` call), but rather it will instead do the rest of the processing and append data to the div instead.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a jQuery feature, but is part of the Event object passed to Javascript event listeners.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

When you bind an event listener to a DOM element the Event object is passed as an argument. That listener is executed when that event is triggered, but each event has a default implementation. When you call `event.preventDefault` is flags the event object as handled, and the default implementation is skipped.

It's most noticable with `<a>` tags when the `click` event, because you might want to prevent the link from being followed. But, it also works on things like keyboard input, touch, and so on.